# How to change sLengthMenu position on the DataTables?

Tags: javascript, css, datatables

I am using datatables for the first time, and I want to switch the places of the searchbox and the sLengthMenu.

I already changed the searchbox to the left with the code below:

CSS:

```
.pull-left{
        float: left !important;
    }
```

JS:

```
$('.dataTables_filter').addClass('pull-left');
```

Now, how can I do the same with the sLenghtMenu, seting it to the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Quite simple.

I used the same logic, changing it to right.

CSS:

```
.pull-right{
        float: right!important;
    }
```

JS:

```
$('.dataTables_length').addClass('pull-right');
```